# MS Project Resource Graph with Allocations Shown

Tags: ms-project

Is it possible to create a view of the resource graph with the task allocation identified like a stacked histogram?

When someone is over-allocated, I want to easily see what they are allocated to.

Answer (score 0):

By displaying the Resource Sheet view or the Resource Usage view and then filtering for overallocated resources, you can see a list of only those resources that are overallocated. Even if you don't filter for overallocated resources, you can tell which ones are because their names are highlighted in red in any resource view. In addition, the indicator field in the Resource Sheet and Resource Usage views will indicate that overallocated resources be leveled.

1. Select Resource Sheet or Resource Usage from the dropdown menu in the View section.
2. Click the Filter dropdown menu in the Data section of the View tab, then Overallocated Resources.
3. Click the Filter dropdown menu, then No Filter to see the complete list of resources once more.

Monthly or quarterly graphs are available. However, neither can be displayed in a single Graph.
Take the steps outlined below.

1. Select Reports -> Visual Reports -> Resource Usage Reports from the Reports menu. Select "Resource Work Summary Report" from the drop-down menu. Select "Months" from the dropdown “Select Level of Usage Data to include in Report” This define the timescale for the cube. Now Click on “View” Button.
   You will receive an EXL Report as a result of this.
   Now Pivot Table Field List is where you'll find everything you need to know about pivot tables.

Make the following Fields settings:

**a. Report Filter as Empty**

**b. Column Labels as Resources**

**c. Row Labels as Time Monthly Labels**

**d. Values as Work / Cost****

Got to Graph Sheet and Change Chart Type : Column -> Stacked Type

2. Return to the Pivot Table Sheet and expand the years in Pivot: As a result, Months are opened under Years. To begin, go to Chart Sheet and select Time Axis -> Format Axis -> Select Alignment -> Text Direction from the drop-down menu and rotate all text to a 270-degree angle.
   Accept.
3. Double-click on the Chart Area and select three coloured stacked bars to change the bar colour.